# Why does the C/C++ bitwise XOR operator care about sign?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

I've been struggling with some low-level messaging for quite some time and it turned out to be an issue with the checksum calculation. I thought the bitwise XOR operator didn't care about sign, so I was using a `QByteArray` to store the bytes, and using the `at` method, that returns a `char`, to calculate the checksum. The messages were properly acknowledged sometimes, but not always.

Looks like the guys on the other end were using `uint8_t` to store the bytes, and 
the checksum was failing in some situations. I solved it by casting the `char` to `uint8_t`, but I'm seriously baffled about that.

Why does the bitwise XOR operator care about sign? I thought it worked on a bit-level, regardless of what they represented. Here's a piece of code I've used to try to understand it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main ()
{    
    uint8_t a = 0b10010101;
    char b    = 0b10010101;

    uint32_t checksum;

    checksum = 55;
    checksum ^= a;
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(checksum) << std::endl;

    checksum = 55;
    checksum ^= b;
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(checksum) << std::endl;    
}
```

Even tho both integers hold the same bits, the operation yields different results in each case.

Comment: It's `cstdio` in C++, not `stdio.h`

Comment: I do not see any or operation here. All I see are XORs

Comment: OR is |.  ^ is XOR

Comment: You're right about the OR / XOR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all you have to remember that it's implementation-defined if `char` is signed or unsigned.

Then you have to remember that values of smaller types like `char` or `uint8_t` are [*promoted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int` (or possibly `unsigned int`) when used in expressions. This promotion brings with it *sign extension* of signed types.

So if `char` is signed, the value `0b10010101` will be promoted to `0b11111111111111111111111110010101` (using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for negative numbers). Which is *very* different from the unsigned value `0b00000000000000000000000010010101`.

Comment: While integral promotions exist, it's fairly obvious that an "in-place" operator like `^=` cannot promote its left-hand operand. The _usual arithmetic conversions_ apply to _binary_ operators: `a = b ^c;`. It's wrong (incorrect generalization) to say that promotion happens is _expressions_, because `a^=b` is also an expression.

Comment: but `a` and `b` are expressions there too.. and operator can't be implemented to work "in-place" with different type of operands. it's more equivalent to `uint32_t operator^=(int32_t a, int32_t b) { uint32_t c = a ^ b; return c; }` with factual operands being `char` and `uint8_t`. I guess, it's just matter of perspective